# window.open location=yes - Firefox 7.01 not showing navigation buttons

Tags: firefox

I have a window that is created via window.open. When the window is created in Firefox 7.01, I turn on the address bar (location=yes). In Firefox 6.01 - 7.01 the forward and back buttons do not show.  It works perfectly in IE. Can someone tell me/show me how to show navigation buttons using windows.open and location=yes in Firefox?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `toolbar=yes` as well.

`location=yes` is for showing the location bar.

Many browsers will default (or even force) some elements you don't request to show anyway, but you should be explicit about all the elements you wish to show rather than relying on this.

[More information is available at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).

Comment: Thanks, but I already have that perameter specified:  window.open("/ConcertPages/SeattleConcerts.htm", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, location=yes, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width=985, height=770");

Comment: I have no idea if this will fix the problem, but I'd try removing the spaces between the options.  According to Mozilla's documentation (link above), *"The string must not contain any blank space, each feature name and value must be separated by a comma."*